# Dev resources for starting WPF Control Development

Tags: .net, wpf, user-controls, controls

One of my upcoming projects needs a rather complex control (functionality wise) and I was wondering what, from experience, are good resources to look at / read? Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [large set of videos on various aspects of WPF that I have found useful](http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos_wpf.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty good book and covers just about every aspect of writing controls [WPF Control Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672330334).

It can also be helpful to start cracking open the source of the built in controls (Reflector or Source Server and default template copies in Blend) and seeing how they work. There are a lot of good patterns that can be reused and make it easier for consumers of your control by following what they're already using.